# Spring Boot External Hibernate JPA Entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a maven project with many separate modules. I would like to move my Spring Boot JPA Entities (annotated with `@javax.persistence.Entity`) in a `common` module, and use that module as a dependency in Spring Boot.

The trouble is that when I do that, Spring Boot can no longer find data for those entities. It returns empty lists. My current workaround is to annotate the models with `@MappedSuperclass` in `common` and have dummy classes in Spring Boot which have the `@Entity` annotations and extend the classes in `common`. This is quite stupid though, there has to be a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly returns an empty list? query methods like `findAll`??

Comment: @JensSchauder Yes. Any kind of query returns empty results.

Comment: Can you post examples of your queries. Some built in Repository queries will not return collections of associated objects, because they are lazy loaded. Regardless of which module you have them in. If the Entities are in the class path and the @JpaRepositories scans for the package that the entities are in, they will be loaded. I suspect either you are changing packages and the scan is looking at the old package structure.